# Why doesn't `nmap -sn 192.168.2.1/150` show the hosts that are up?

Tags: network, nmap, network-scanners

I wanted to know the hosts that were up on my network. So while working with Nmap I couldn't understand why using the command `nmap -sn 192.168.2.1/150` it didn't want to tell me the hosts that were up, But then after using `nmap -sn 192.168.2.*`, it worked for me instead of the other one.
Can somebody explain me this event?

Comment: Why did you use `192.168.2.1/150`? What were you thinking that would do?

Comment: Maybe they meant the range `192.168.2.1-150`.

Comment: I was using 192.168.2.1/150 because the devices of my network are above 192.168.2.100 :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your first example uses the [CIDR notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing#CIDR_notation) to specify the host range as a netmask.

But since `/150` is an illegal value for an IPv4 subnet mask, `nmap` falls back to the largest plausible value which is `/32` (because an IPv4 address only has 32 bits), making you scan exactly one host:

```
$ nmap -sn 192.168.2.1/150

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-30 19:45 CET
Illegal netmask in "192.168.2.1/150". Assuming /32 (one host)
Nmap scan report for easy.box.local (192.168.2.1)
Host is up (0.0026s latency).
Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.01 seconds
```

The CIDR-noted range equivalent to

```
$ nmap -sn "192.168.2.*"
```

is

```
$ nmap -sn 192.168.2.1/24
```

because `255.255.255.0` has 24 leading `1` bits.

You can verify that assumption with more verbosity (`-v`):

```
$ nmap -sn -v 192.168.2.1/24

Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2017-12-30 19:58 CET
Initiating Ping Scan at 19:58
Scanning 256 hosts [2 ports/host]
Completed Ping Scan at 19:58, 2.40s elapsed (256 total hosts)
Initiating Parallel DNS resolution of 256 hosts. at 19:58
Completed Parallel DNS resolution of 256 hosts. at 19:58, 0.06s elapsed
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.0 [host down]
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.1 [host down]
...
Nmap scan report for 192.168.2.255 [host down]
Read data files from: /usr/bin/../share/nmap
Nmap done: 256 IP addresses (2 hosts up) scanned in 2.47 seconds
```

Answer (score 2):

The specified network to scan in this command `nmap -sn 192.168.2.1/150` is invalid.

You requested prefix 150, but it is invalid.

If you want to scan `192.168.2.*`, you should use prefix 24.